# Play store weird crash report

Tags: android, view

In my application placed on Play Store I reserve weird crash report. I can find from where this error come.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod (View.java:6464)
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (View.java:6421)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7870)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7839)
  at android.view.View.access$3600 (View.java:886)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:29363)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7811)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Can some help me and tell me how can I know more about this error ?

Thanks